# dynamically repeat Barcode or a ref

Tags: php, css, printing, barcode

i have project requires to print Barcode Label  simply i'm using barcodephp.com script 
to get my result in auto Complicate  form and this is the result as 1 result and 1 img

```
 <a href="barcode/test_1D.php?text=first-red-30" target="_blank"><img src="barcode/test_1D.php?text=model-color-size" alt="barcode"></a>
```

user gonna use ZEBRA BarCode/labels Printers and it needs special templates printing format in width , height of  label size also the blank space between each label i was gonna do it in separated css file depend on label and roll size .
what we need now is how to dynamically repeating the labels as user needs.
with a dialog box asking him  how many labels he need and once he inserted value its repeated with the format  i did with css .